# GTM Custom Variables from li attributes

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

(Preface: I am not a coder, so if I've misrepresented something here please let me know and I will try to correct or provide more info.)

We have a series of search results presented to users in an unordered list with a parent class followed by a lot of useful metadata, including the list position. Something like this:

```
<li class="article-panel" data-articletype="knowledgebase" data-list-position="1">...</li>
<li class="article-panel" data-articletype="blog" data-list-position="2">...</li>
<li class="article-panel" data-articletype="news" data-list-position="3">...</li>
```

I'm trying to create a series of variables to allow us to use the metadata in events, so that we can track the list position of a clicked object as the event's label or value. The problem I'm running into is that because each of these objects uses the same class name, the variable is always returning only the first set of values, no matter which object I click on.

```
Variable configuration: 
DOM Element
CSS Selector
Element Selector = .article-panel
Attribute Name = data-articletype
```

Using the example, the above variable is always returning "knowledgebase", even when I click on the news or blog article (and the same goes for data-list-position always returning "1".)

How do I specify that I want to return the variables of the object clicked without always referring only to the first instance of that class in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tips, all. Unfortunately no matter what we did we couldn't find a way to get Google Analytics to register events with variables higher in the CSS tree; in fact, it looks like something is happening with our implementation to prevent any triggers in that UL level from firing consistently. We've decided to just add the metadata tags further down to the actual interaction event, so that it registers at the click level and avoids any CSS-Selector triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Just create custom (data layer type) variable e.g.:

```
gtm.element.dataset.articletype
```

It should catch values placed in custom attributes. Then You can use it with events etc.

On the other hand if link tag is placed directly in li tag you should rather use something like this:

```
gtm.element.parentNode.dataset.articletype
```

to access data from parent.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I saw you work for Blizzard Entertainment. That's dope. Unfortunately, the solution I'll present is not non-developer friendly, but hopefully you'll be able to implement it.

I actually was able to test this on the main Blizzard website, in the store. It's not quite the same as the code you posted, but the logic should be very similar!

I recommend creating a **Custom HTML tag** for this. I've written the follow script, which you can paste into the **Custom HTML Tag** field:

```
<script>
(function ($) {
   $(function () {
      $('li.article-panel').click(function() {
        var label = $(this).attr('data-list-position');
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'GAEvent', 
            'eventCat': 'Your Event Category', 
            'eventAction': 'Your Event Action', 
            'eventLabel': 'Item Position = ' + label,
            'gaNonInt': false
        });
      });
   });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

You can use a pageview trigger for this tag. Set it to fire only on the pages where your list exists. Don't worry, the tag doesn't push data, unless the JQuery function is activated via a click on your `<li>` element.

Now, in order for this to work, you need to have variables set up for Event Category (eventCat), Event Action (eventAction), Event Label (eventLabel), ect. My variables are likely different from yours, so you'll need to swap them out.

Inside the `dataLayer` array (found in the attached function), you'll also need to change out the string attached to each variable. So, set eventCat to the Event Category name you desire, and do the same with eventAction. I set up the eventLabel to show you the list position of the item clicked. It should read as 'Item Position = (item position #)' in GA. Make sure you do not delete any single quotes. They are necessary!

I recommend getting a developer to help out, if you can! I can walk you through what each piece of the function does, but it can be difficult to understand. That said, let me know if you have any questions! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the meta data of a clicked list element you should not use a DOM type variable. Rather you should enable the click variables from the built-in variable set, specifically `{{Click Element}}`.

If you do that `{{Click Element}}` will be updated automatically and will contain the clicked element. You can then use this in a HTML tag or a custom javascript variable to get your data attribute via `{{Click Element}}.getAttribute('data-articletype')`.

Comment: This is the solution we ultimately went with. I was already using the built-in click event, but the metadata I wanted wasn't inside the click element. Because we were unable to resolve the issue with the metadata being further up the CSS tree, we just moved everything down.